# How to inject domain constraints into a Grails GSP?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

My domain object:

```
class Fizz {
    String buzz

    static constraints = {
        buzz (blank: false, inList: ['foo', 'bar'])
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
class FizzController {
    def index() {
        render(
            view: "fizz",
            model: [
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

Inside the `<body>` tag of my GSP (`fizz.gsp`):

```
<label for="buzz">Buzz:</label>
<g:select name="buzz" from="${Fizz.constraints.buzz.inList}" />
```

When I run the app I get a runtime exception rendering the page, stating:

> Cannot get property 'constraints' on null object

So `Fizz` is null, which tells me I'm not injecting the GSP correctly. It *may* have something to do with my empty `model` array (back in the controller):

```
model: [
]
```

But since I'm accessing a static property here, I'm not sure how to inject the model with a static value (if that is even the cause of what's happening here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to import the class in your gsp:

```
 <%@ page import="com.someapp.Fizz" %>
```